# Android: Removing child fragraments when parent fragment is removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragmentmanager

I have an Activity with BottomNavigationView and fragment container (FrameLayout). Each tab in bottom navigation has related a TabFragment (TabFragment1, TabFragment2 etc) and each TabFragment is parent fragment for nested fragments. Nested fragments are added to back stack to be restored after back button is pressed (every TabFragment has its own back stack). My question is: should I manually remove nested fragment in each TabFragment when tab fragments are replaced in Activity? Are nested fragment destroyed when parent fragment is destroyed? Is back stack cleared after its fragment is destroyed? I want to avoid memory leak. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this. But when I use ViewPager, if I replace ViewPager with other fragment ViewPager will be replaced but the fragment in ViewPager not remove. So when I replace ViewPager I do this.

```
 for( Fragment f : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
     if( f.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Your nested fragment name"))
         transaction.remove(f);
 }
```